# Bulk Update of Particular fields In Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, hadoop2

I have a scenario while was working on Hbase. Initially I have to bulkupload a csv file to Hbase table.Which I could do successfully by using Hbase bulkloading.
Now I want to update a particular field in hbase table by comparing to an new csv provided and if the value is updated have to maintain a flag which says the rowkey was updated. Any hint how I can do it easily. 
Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HBase maintains versions for each cell. As long as you have the row key with you, you get a handle of the row, and you can just use put to add the updated column. Internally it maintains the versions, and you can have access to history of the updated values too.

However, you need comparing too, as I can see. So after bulk loading the fastest you can do it, use a map reduce as have HBase as source and sink. Look [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html) at 7.2.2 section. 
The idea is have mapreduce perform the scan, do comparision in map, and write the new updated put in output. Its like a basic fetch, modify and update sequence. But we are using map reduce parallel feature as we are dealing with large amount of data